# Coloring a plot from a list of data with colors in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, rstudio, pca

Hi I've been struggling with R
I did a PCA with some data, and now I need to color the PCA dotplot in function on what group the data belongs to.

Example of my data used for the PCA (the table is much longer)

```
    A   R   N   C
A   43 121  113 34
R   14 272  190 456
N   145 182 392 123
C   62  32  231 32
```

Exemple of my list of colors:

```
A blue
R red
N red
C yellow
```

So far I did this:

```
color=c('blue','red','yellow')
plot(result.acp$scores[,1], result.acp$scores[,2], col=color)
```

But the colors do not match what I want them do be...

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
> dput(head(m.acp$scores))
structure(c(0.485248382360341, 1.22814614717322, 1.41375370895067, 
1.85498947175758, -0.375697094166481, 1.34378781510518, 1.51863186603447, 
0.0572515048241142, -0.0568916310833516, 0.206543014267263, -0.343532082404636, 
0.381649504516637, 1.97718761386959, -1.94694408760922, 0.280457723526986, 
-0.265669310511105, 1.72386086473253, -1.68640891503048, 0.672268772844792, 
2.49620220365566, -1.30569962068436, -2.96457420077961, 1.05873011149105, 
0.249856229642777, 0.752740909620085, -0.3221475597597, -0.404971059387798, 
-0.352104569288916, -1.59955880042156, 0.333186494105438, 1.01661633422811, 
-0.524424365814158, -1.7920923623531, -0.118129421711271, -0.73363898593327, 
0.773671927192673, 0.345338193690839, -0.147960273603448, -1.75910531541936, 
0.470479642531196, 1.66771948007324, 0.858806139744018, 0.23677924891001, 
0.414419626952358, 0.0739894762692486, 0.195277617408496, 0.665251426743185, 
-0.0762532572287367, 1.16997815118309, -0.182032179249172, -0.631929337424788, 
0.0308147786374188, 1.95340300164186, 0.375321240022787, 0.960836703335612, 
0.183269601943323, -0.474379307207703, -0.366060693508836, -2.44695520772428, 
-0.148494705705629, 0.98954553138859, -0.948420509262348, -1.43040720187175, 
-0.813792180978826, -0.668336260091166, 1.44697150834988, 2.15084852373618, 
0.660040624486677, 0.603497901938454, 0.71258499250433, -0.37074063114479, 
-1.73475877465446, 0.545840674222426, -1.15093599362176, 2.25309487011121, 
-1.20269177035014, 0.0873434143238955, 2.27247541012993, 0.562854625458883, 
0.27543018066447, 0.133753878088941, 0.00449996616098378, -0.227465329112754, 
-0.213097298055626, 1.28987242747272, -0.498171201060435, 0.672676976975279, 
-0.703021260403972, -0.118017362131157, -0.563645828724812, 0.547975716027795, 
1.88086974178728, 0.135685047918279, 0.714498879661545, -0.389199450099059, 
0.974113605475622, 0.336700529414482, 0.669737969811285, 0.256286261107131, 
-0.144265911846499, 0.129062364254905, 0.117900930006798, 0.462989706826572, 
-0.730213304706471, -0.723150151495445, 1.82998913621228, -0.0485822435981942, 
0.717875231696143, 0.335399340465998, -0.022113090137115, -0.0205652022391104, 
-0.0412768969464503, 0.120177653804699, 0.0474613997209151, 7.25114412958305e-16, 
-9.29811783123569e-16, -3.04617442381527e-15, -1.13103970633688e-15, 
2.08166817117217e-16, -5.27355936696949e-16), .Dim = c(6L, 20L
), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "Q"), c("Comp.1", 
"Comp.2", "Comp.3", "Comp.4", "Comp.5", "Comp.6", "Comp.7", "Comp.8", 
"Comp.9", "Comp.10", "Comp.11", "Comp.12", "Comp.13", "Comp.14", 
"Comp.15", "Comp.16", "Comp.17", "Comp.18", "Comp.19", "Comp.20"
)))
```

Comment: Can you show the dput of the examples to understand the structure i.e. whether it is `data.frame`, `matrix`, `list` ?  The `list` of colors is that a `data.frame` or a `list`

Comment: @akrun both data are tables with headers (the table that contains the colors has more columns with other 'useless' data)

Comment: There is a `table` class object.  Is it that class?

Comment: @akrun yes, I opened it using read.table()

Comment: As I don't have the exact structure of your data, I created one  in the solution below.  Please check if that is what you wanted

Comment: If you have showed by pasting the structure of your dataset i.e. `dput(result.acp$scores)` and `dput(list1)`, would be easier to debug the issue.

Comment: > dput(m.acp$scores)
structure(c(0.485248382360341, 1.22814614717322, 1.41375370895067, 
1.85498947175758, -0.375697094166481, 1.34378781510518, 2.09458109950812, 
0.783038294729706, 0.470564424924018, -2.98725335902823, -3.04965049259398), .Dim = c(20L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
"R", "N", "D", "C", "Q", "E", "G", "H", "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", 
"P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"), c("Comp.1", "Comp.2", "Comp.3", 
"Comp.4", "Comp.5", "Comp.6", "Comp.7", "Comp.8", "Comp.9", "Comp.10", 
"Comp.11", "Comp.12", "Comp.16", 
"Comp.17", "Comp.18", "Comp.19", "Comp.20")))

Comment: I had to remove some values since it was too long

Comment: the structure won't work if you remove instead use `dput(head(m.accp$scores))` and your list

Comment: dput(list1)
list(R = "orange", H = "orange", K = "orange", L = "pink", M = "pink", 
    v = "pink", C = "yellow", N = "blue", D = "blue", Q = "blue", 
    E = "blue", A = "green", G = "green", P = "green", S = "green", 
    W = "magenta", Y = "magenta")

Comment: I'm only removing it here, because it says my answer is too long

Comment: I understand, but if you copy/paste that output in your console, it returns error `Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  dims [product 400] do not match the length of object [11]
>`.  So, please use `dput` on the `head(m.acp$scores)`

Comment: I edited the question to include head(m.acp$scores)

Comment: In your dput, the column names are different compared to row names.  But, in the example showed, it is the same i.e. `Comp.1`, `Comp.2` etc compared to `A`, `R`, `N` row names.  So, if you are comparing two columns, what would be the colours?  If the comparison is between rows, it is possible though

Comment: Row names and column names should be the same.... The table used at the begining has the same

Comment: In that case, please change the column names to rownames and then apply the function

Comment: I updated the post.  Here `scores <- head(m.acp$scores)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `list` of colors is a `list`, we can subset the `list` elements based on the column name of the data used and that would go into the `col`

```
plot(result.acp$scores[,1], result.acp$scores[,2], 
          col = unlist(lst1[names(result.acp$scores)[1:2]]))
```

which can be wrapped into a function and pass only the position index

```
f1 <- function(ind) {
  plot(result.acp$scores[,ind[1]], result.acp$scores[, ind[2]],
  col = unlist(lst1[names(result.acp$scores)[ind]]))
}
f1(1:2)
f1(2:3)
f1(3:4)
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset, the dataset is a `matrix`, so we use `colnames` instead of `names`

```
scores1 <- scores[, 1:6]
colnames(scores1) <- row.names(scores1)
plot(scores1[,1], scores1[,2], 
        col = unlist(list1[colnames(scores1)[1:2]]))
```

#### data

```
result.acp <- list(scores = structure(list(A = c(43L, 14L, 145L, 62L), R = c(121L, 
272L, 182L, 32L), N = c(113L, 190L, 392L, 231L), C = c(34L, 456L, 
123L, 32L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "R", "N", 
"C")))

lst1 <- list(A = 'blue', R = 'red', N = 'red', C = 'yellow')
```

Comment: I get the following error: 'supplied colors is neither numeric nor character'.... This is my color list: list1 <- list(R'= 'orange', H='orange', K='orange', L='pink',M=pink', V='pink', C='yellow', N='blue', D='blue', Q='blue', E='blue', A='green', G='green', P='green',S='green', T='green',F='magenta', W='magenta', Y='magenta')

Comment: @Lau As I said I don't have your data structure.  Please test it on the 'data' I showed and if it is returning error.  For me, it is working. Also, please use `dput` to get the structure of your example datas